# JS Replace only replacing first pair

Tags: javascript

My code is:

```js
function fms(e) {
  eq = e
  eq = eq.replace('f(', '<em>f</em>(')
  eq = eq.replace(' / ', ' &#247; ')
  eq = eq.replace('{', '<sup>')
  eq = eq.replace('}', '</sup>')
  return eq
}
a = fms('x{y} x{y}')
console.log(a)
```

And it is supposed to add sup around whatever is in the {}, but: my a variable only has  around the first pair, and the second left unchanged:

```
x<sup>y</sup> x{y}
```

I am puzzled. If you know why, make sure to let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Use `replaceAll` instead of `replace` since you are using a string to be replaced by another sting.

**String.prototype.replace()**

The `replace()` method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a `string` or a `RegExp`, and the replacement can be a `string` or a `function` to be called for each match. **If pattern is a string, only the first occurrence will be replaced.**

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
function fms(e) {
  eq = e
  eq = eq.replaceAll('f(', '<em>f</em>(')
  eq = eq.replaceAll(' / ', ' &#247; ')
  eq = eq.replaceAll('{', '<sup>')
  eq = eq.replaceAll('}', '</sup>')
  return eq
}
a = fms('x{y} x{y}');
console.log(a)
```

**How to make `String.replace` replace all the occurances?**

You can replace all the occurances of a sring using `replace` itself, if we make use of a `regex` instead of the string.

**Working Example**

```js
function fms(e) {
  eq = e;
  eq = eq.replace(/f\(/g, '<em>f</em>(')
  eq = eq.replace(/\//g, ' &#247; ')
  eq = eq.replace(/{/g, '<sup>')
  eq = eq.replace(/}/g, '</sup>')
  return eq
}
a = fms('x{y} x{y}');
console.log(a);
```

Comment: I formatted OP's question so you mbeat me to the answer ;)